# Calculate the relative value of an item within an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there an elegant, possibly ES6 solution to create a new object from an object. The new object should show for each item of the object the relative percentage to the total of the object.

```js
// init Object
const obj = {
  "PHP": 9,
  "HTML": 5,
  "JS": 6,
};

// expected Object
const newObj = {
  "PHP": 45, // 45%
  "HTML": 25,
  "JS": 30,
};
```

**My approach is**
Calculate the sum of the obj. This is my base (const base = 20). Then i use `Object.keys` and `map()` function to calculate. That three steps. Maybe is goes shorter.

Comment: @JeffBowman Thank you for your answer! I almost thought so. Then I'll put the steps in a separate function and it will be short enough.Maybe there will be a new function in the near future that does it itself. Merci

Comment: Converted to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dictionary like you propose, you can break it apart using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), process the entries, process the entries using `map`, and then reconstitute the object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). This is the most direct answer to "create a new object from an object" as your quesiton asks.

Though this might appear more clever/functional than your proposed method (sum the values, then iterate through the keys using `Object.keys` and process them one at a time), I don't think it would be any faster, shorter, or more maintainable than what you've proposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And we had already said the most important thing in the comments. I will mark this answer as accepted because I think it is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

What Jeff proposed is one of the solutions out there, you can also first calculate the "out of" total from all the key/value pairs that you have in `obj` and then just recreate the initial object with the calculation of the percentage as you are looping through the object like in the example below:

```js
const obj = {
  "PHP": 9,
  "HTML": 5,
  "JS": 6,
};

const total = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const result = {};

for (const key in obj) {
   const percentage = (obj[key] * 100) / total;
   result[key] = percentage;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**lodash** if you don't mind:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

total = _.sum(_.values(obj));
result = _.mapValues(obj, (v) => v / total * 100);

console.log(result); //{PHP: 45, HTML: 25, JS: 30}
```